# Avalonedit: Use line tab instead of paragraph tab?

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

I'm currently writing a basic word processing program, and I'm using Avalonedit because it's easy to use and handles large volumes of text more efficiently than the built-in WPF controls.

One of the issues that I'm running into is that when you tab or space at the beginning of a paragraph, the *entire* paragraph is indented, rather than the line that you are on.

Is there a way to change this in Avalonedit?

Comment: You might have more luck asking on the [Using AvalonEdit (WPF Text Editor)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor) page on the Code Project website.

Comment: Thank you; I've posted there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `textEditor.Options.InheritWordWrapIndentation = false;`